# We have a density function: $p_{X,Y}(x,y)=ce^{-y}, 0\leq x<y<x+1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, probability-theory

$$p_{XY}(x, y)= ce^{-y},\quad 0\leq x \lt y\lt (x+1)$$

I need to find $c$.

My try:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\int_x^{x+1}ce^{-y}dydx = \int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{y}ce^{-y}dxdy = \ldots =1$$

Is the idea correct, are the bounds of the integral correct (I did it both ways, to see if I understand it).

Let's say that I would be interested in $P(X<1)$ I would do:
$$P(X<1) = \int_0^1\int_x^{x+1}ce^{-y}dy$$

Are the above two processes of solving correct?

Comment: First integral correct.  Second - limits on x should be (y-1,y).

Comment: @herbsteinberg I see, is this correct, or is it mathlover's answer?

Comment: My   comment was before mathlover answer.  Both same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that $0 \lt x \lt y \lt x + 1 \lt \infty$

So the first integral is correct. For the second, when $y \in (0,1), 0 \lt x \lt y$ and for $y \in (1, \infty), y-1 \lt x  \lt y$

So the integral should be,

$ \displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_0^y  c \cdot e^{-y} ~dx ~dy + \int_1^\infty \int_{y-1}^y  c \cdot e^{-y} ~dx ~dy ~= 1$

Comment: @amWhy It is ok, he got into more detail, since I wouldn't know what exactly to do

Comment: I thought the downvote was because the answer was wrong

Comment: I did not downvote your answer.  If we start accusing users who give constructive feedback, of downvoting and such antics, which you've just done, and are entirely incorrect in your accusation, then this site is worthless.

Comment: @amWhy sorry for assuming you downvoted, the downvote  coincided with the comments and hence I thought so. But in any case I am giving my point of view on it. Sometimes I may see a question late and if I feel like answering a non-PSQ because I see that the comment is not complete or I have a better explanation or a different idea, I will answer and I do not see a problem with that.

Comment: I think it's natural for us to connect two events; not problem.  I deleted my first comment;  I appreciate your follow up, Math Lover.

Answer (score 1):

Why reverse the order of integration in solving for $c$?

\begin{aligned}\int_0^{\infty}\int_x^{x+1}ce^{-y}dydx =\int_0^\infty \left(-ce^{-x-1}+ce^{-x}\right) dx &=\lim_{t \to \infty} \left(ce^{-x-1}-ce^{-x}\right) \Big]_0^t\\&=\left(ce^{-1} -c\right)\cdot\lim_{t \to \infty}e^{-t} - ce^{-1}+c \\&=c(1-e^{-1})\end{aligned}

\begin{aligned}\int_0^1 \int_0^y  c  e^{-y} dx dy + \int_1^\infty \int_{y-1}^y  c e^{-y} dx dy &=\int_0^1 ce^{-y}y dy+ \int_1^\infty c e^{-y}dy
\\&=\left[-ce^{-y}y\right]_0^1+\left[-ce^{-y}\right]_0^1+\lim_{t \to \infty} \left[-ce^{-y} \right]_1^t
\\&=-ce^{-1}-ce^{-1}+c+\lim_{t \to \infty} -ce^{-t} +ce^{-1}\\&= c(1-e^{-1})\end{aligned}

Seems like extra work to do more work. Pardon my candor, I just point this out as something to consider.